# errors when compiling c code with ffmpeg library

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I've installed ffmpeg library in my new ubuntu 16.04 OS. When I tried to compile my c code, I got the following strange errors:

```
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavutil.a(hwcontext_vaapi.o): In function `vaapi_device_free':
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:861: undefined reference to `XCloseDisplay'
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavutil.a(hwcontext_vaapi.o): In function `vaapi_device_create':
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:891: undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:896: undefined reference to `vaGetDisplay'
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:903: undefined reference to `XDisplayName'
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:893: undefined reference to `XDisplayName'
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:917: undefined reference to `vaGetDisplayDRM'
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:891: undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:893: undefined reference to `XDisplayName'
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:898: undefined reference to `XDisplayName'
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavutil.a(hwcontext_vdpau.o): In function `vdpau_device_create':
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vdpau.c:431: undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vdpau.c:437: undefined reference to `XDisplayString'
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vdpau.c:439: undefined reference to `XDefaultScreen'
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vdpau.c:439: undefined reference to `vdp_device_create_x11'
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vdpau.c:433: undefined reference to `XDisplayName'
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavutil.a(hwcontext_vdpau.o): In function `vdpau_device_free':
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vdpau.c:410: undefined reference to `XCloseDisplay'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:30: recipe for target 'video_analysis' failed
make: *** [video_analysis] Error 1
```

I've reinstalled ffmpeg library multiple times using the following configurations:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-libass \
  --enable-libfdk-aac \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libopus \
  --enable-libtheora \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-nonfree
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make
```

The installation process was successful each time. But when I tried to compile my own c code, I always encountered the same errors as mentioned above. I have no idea about that...
Here is the makefile I used:

**EDIT:**

```
FFMPEG_LIBS=    libavdevice                        \
                libavformat                        \
                libavfilter                        \
                libavcodec                         \
                libswresample                      \
                libswscale                         \
                libavutil                          \

TARGET = video_analysis
LIBS = -lX11 -lm -lvdpau -lva
CC = gcc
CFLAGS += -O2 -g -O0
CFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --cflags $(FFMPEG_LIBS)) $(CFLAGS)
LDLIBS := $(shell pkg-config --libs $(FFMPEG_LIBS)) $(LDLIBS)

.PHONY: default all clean

default: $(TARGET)
all: default

OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c))
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.h)

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PRECIOUS: $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDLIBS) $(LIBS) -o $@

clean:
    -rm -f *.o
    -rm -f $(TARGET)
```

**EDIT:**

Afer swapping $(LIBS) and $(LDLIBS) to be $(LDLIBS) $(LIBS) at line 30, it looks much better, but the compiler still reports the following errors:

```
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavutil.a(hwcontext_vaapi.o): In function `vaapi_device_create':
/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:896: undefined reference to `vaGetDisplay'
/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:917: undefined reference to `vaGetDisplayDRM'
```

I have no idea which library is still missing? It looks as if libva were still missing?...
I got the answer by myself...Have a look at here: [errors of 'vaGetDisplay' and `vaGetDisplayDRM'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995044/errors-of-vagetdisplay-and-vagetdisplaydrm)

Comment: It seems you forget to link your application with some needed libraries. Search for those functions to see which libraries are needed.

Comment: most of the missing functions are in libX11 (missing -lX11), for vaGetDisplay and vaGetDisplayDRM and vdp_device_create_X11 I do not know. Try googling them or man them to see in which library they are defined.

Comment: @BrunoLevy I've installed libX11, and put -lX11 in my Makefile. BUt the errors didn't disappear. Is it possible that ffmpeg library couldn't find libX11? Do I need to configure the path while installing libX11 so that it's recognizable by ffmpeg library?

Comment: Could you show us your makefile ? -lX11 should be *after* -lffmpeg

Comment: @BrunoLevy I've uploaded the makefile above...

Comment: swap $(LIBS) and $(LDLIBS) in line 30 (as I said, -lX11 should be $after$ -lffmpeg).

Comment: I swapped these two and it did make the world a better place! the error complains are shortened to be: /root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavutil.a(hwcontext_vaapi.o): In function `vaapi_device_create':
/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:896: undefined reference to `vaGetDisplay'
/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:917: undefined reference to `vaGetDisplayDRM'

Comment: I had added -lva, but the compiler still complained as if I hadn't added...

Comment: @BrunoLevy and I had also already installed libva before...

Comment: It is not the *installation* order, it is the order of the -lxxx options in the command line sent to the linker that matters (-lva should be after -lffmpeg)

Comment: @BrunoLevy you're right! I sill come across the above mentioned errors where the compiler seems still not to be able to find libva, though I've installed it already...

Comment: @Kindermann did you find my answer useful? Have you thought about [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)?

Comment: @Josh de Kock Thank you for your answer. It's been very helpful. Therefore I have voted your answer up. (one of the 3 upvotes came actually from me). However, your answer didn't solve the complete puzzle...Hence, I couldn't accept it as the solution. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995044/errors-of-vagetdisplay-and-vagetdisplaydrm

Comment: @Kindermann I missed your edit (which was 8 days after my answer). Try adding `libva-drm` and `libva-x11` to the PKG_CFG_LIBS variable.

Answer (score 11):

You need to link with the libraries which provide those functions as well as FFmpeg.

The linker flags you need to add are (with their respective errors):

`-lvdpau` - [libvdpau-dev](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvdpau)

```
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vdpau.c:439: undefined reference to `vdp_device_create_x11'
```

`-lva` - [libva-dev](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libva)

```
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:896: undefined reference to `vaGetDisplay'
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:917: undefined reference to `vaGetDisplayDRM'
```

`-lX11` - [libx11-dev](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libx11)

```
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:861: undefined reference to `XCloseDisplay'
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:898: undefined reference to `XDisplayName'
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vdpau.c:431: undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vdpau.c:437: undefined reference to `XDisplayString'
/home/widerstand/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vdpau.c:439: undefined reference to `XDefaultScreen'
```

These flags need to be added after your `-lav*` linker flags.

---

Edit: OP added makefile

You can also use pkg-config for all the libraries.

```
FFMPEG_LIBS=    libavdevice                        \
                libavformat                        \
                libavfilter                        \
                libavcodec                         \
                libswresample                      \
                libswscale                         \
                libavutil

PKG_CFG_LIBS=   x11                                \
                vdpau                              \
                libva                              \
                $(FFMPEG_LIBS)

TARGET = video_analysis
LIBS = -lm
CC = gcc
CFLAGS += -O2 -g -O0
CFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --cflags $(PKG_CFG_LIBS)) $(CFLAGS)
LDLIBS := $(shell pkg-config --libs $(PKG_CFG_LIBS)) $(LDLIBS)

.PHONY: default all clean

default: $(TARGET)
all: default

OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c))
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.h)

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PRECIOUS: $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

clean:
    -rm -f *.o
    -rm -f $(TARGET)
```

Comment: my compiler still complained the same error till now though i had added -lvdpau and -lva flags. see above the makefile...

Comment: with your proposed makefile, I got the following error:Package libx11 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libx11.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libx11' found

Comment: In fact, I had installed the newest version of libx11-dev before...the same for libvdpau and libva...

Comment: @JoshdeKock Your way to solve compile/link error is very good. It comes out that the "order" of flags on GCC is also important. I have posted an answer to this question on the other thread, too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995044/errors-of-vagetdisplay-and-vagetdisplaydrm/39217028#39217028