# Linking against ffmpeg libs on Rust gives `vdp_device_create_x11` (libvdpau-dev missing?)

Tags: ffmpeg, rust, linker, shared-libraries

I'm trying to link against `ffmpeg` libraries, in rust, and getting as the only error:

```
undefined reference to `vdp_device_create_x11'
```

Here's the libs linked:

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=build.rs");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=z");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=dl");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=X11");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=vdpau");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=va");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=va-drm");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=va-x11");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=xcb");
}
```

On C++ I used to link with all these `libs` above + some for `GTK` and it worked. Don't know why it wont work now.

On [errors when compiling c code with ffmpeg library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850260/errors-when-compiling-c-code-with-ffmpeg-library) it says that I should link against `-lvdpau - libvdpau-dev`

I tried adding

```
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=vdpau-dev");
```

but I get

```
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvdpau-dev
```

Even though I installed `libvdpau-dev`. Indeed,

```
ldconfig -p | grep vdpau
        libvdpau.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvdpau.so.1
        libvdpau.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvdpau.so
```

Why `libdpau-dev` is missing? I'm on ubuntu 20, `apt-get install -y libdpau-dev`. Finny thing is that C++ compiles perfectly in this same docker container without any modifications and without `libdpau-dev`

**UPDATE:**

```
nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvdpau.so | grep x11
0000000000001d50 T vdp_device_create_x11
```

**UPDATE:**

```
note: /usr/bin/ld: /home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/target/debug/deps/libffmpeg_sys_next-109176c9182219d2.rlib(hwcontext_vdpau.o): in function `vdpau_device_create':
          hwcontext_vdpau.c:(.text+0x686): undefined reference to `vdp_device_create_x11'
```

The file hwcontext_vdpau.o is from ffmpeg: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/hwcontext__vdpau_8c_source.html

My theory of why it worked for your case but not mine is that in your case you link these libraries after the code that uses `vdp_device_create_x11`. In my case, I think it links my code against the `libs` I provided `+ ffmpeg libs`. So maybe `ffmpeg libs` come after or before the `libs` I provided.

Well, since I'm linking against the project that links with ffmpeg, I think this is what's happening:

my_code is being linked against `ffmpeg-sys-next crate + libs` I provided. Where `ffmpeg-sys-next` crate contains the `ffmpeg libs`. I just don't know if the order is

ffmpeg-sys-next crate + libs I provided

or

libs I provided + ffmpeg-sys-next crate.

If ffmpeg needs vdp_device_create_x11, then vdp_device_create_x11 should come before ffmpeg or after?

Is it possible to control if the crate dependencies are linked after or before the libs I provided?

**UPDATE:**

```
Running `rustc --crate-name liborwell_rust --edition=2018 src/main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -Cembed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=a40686dab33e6453 -C extra-filename=-a40686dab33e6453 --out-dir /home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/target/debug/deps -C incremental=/home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/target/debug/incremental -L dependency=/home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/target/debug/deps --extern ffmpeg_next=/home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/target/debug/deps/libffmpeg_next-c150275f8ec2ece5.rlib --extern liborwellprofile_protobuf_rust=/home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/target/debug/deps/libliborwellprofile_protobuf_rust-85a803bf8441d976.rlib --extern phf=/home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/target/debug/deps/libphf-0282e4d662343769.rlib --extern protobuf=/home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/target/debug/deps/libprotobuf-525fd12c456cb486.rlib -l static=z -l dylib=dl -l dylib=vdpau -l static=X11 -l dylib=va -l dylib=va-drm -l dylib=va-x11 -l dylib=xcb -L native=/home/dev/orwell/deps/ffmpeg/build/linux/x86_64/lib`
```

Looks like the ffmpeg libraries are the last thing passed to the compiler/linker: `-L native=/home/dev/orwell/deps/ffmpeg/build/linux/x86_64/lib`

Comment: Did you put the libraries in the same order as on C/C++?

Comment: @Jmb yes.......

Comment: What's the full error message? It should include information about the `.so` that's asking for `vdp_device_create_x11` (something like: `foo.so: undefined reference…`)

Comment: @Jmb take a look at the update

Comment: `vdp` should come after `ffmpeg-sys`. However, I thought cargo always put user-provided libs after rust libs, so I'm confused why it doesn't work for you. Does the `-v` or `-vv` cargo option give any insights?

Comment: @Jmb take a look at my update. `rustc` passed `-L native=/home/dev/orwell/deps/ffmpeg/build/linux/x86_64/lib` as its last flag. It comes after all the libs, including vdpau. Don't know, however, if it actually tries to link vdpau first then the ffmpeg libs.

Comment: The `-L` (upper-case) is not a problem, it only affects the search path, not the libraries. More surprising is that there are no references to `ffmpeg-sys`, only `ffmpeg`. What happens if you add an explicit dependency for `ffmpeg-sys` in your `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: @jmb added it but error still the same :(

Comment: @jbm actually it may be adding ffmpeg-sys already: https://pastebin.com/DANdDv07 it's just in those strange build names

Comment: It would be very handy if you could put an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on github or somewhere. Otherwise all we can do is guess at what might be wrong. The MCVE should be minimal code that when compiled gives the same error, together with build.rs and Cargo.toml.

Answer (score 0):

*libvdpau-dev* is the name of the development package, but *libvdpau* being the name of the library and the shared object file (libvdpau.so) you should pass `-lvdpau` to the linker.
That answer you linked to says to add that flag and then gives a link to the dev package.

```rust
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=vdpau");
```